# "Have someone do/doing someting", "be having someone do/doing something" in context

Tags: grammar, causatives, causative-have

Let's say I told my assistant to write a report and they are doing it at the moment. Which of the following sentence is correct to commumicate the idea?

> I **have** my assistant **write** a report, she is unavailable at the moment.
>
> I **have** my assistant **writing** a report, she is unavailable at the moment.
>
> I **am having** my assistant **write** a report, she is unavailable at the moment.
>
> I **am having** my assistant **writing** a report, she is unavailable at the moment.

Comment: The idiom is: to have someone do something,**not doing something**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both (2) `I have my assistant writing a report, she is unavailable at the moment` and (3) `I am having my assistant write a report, she is unavailable at the moment` are possible, although (3) sounds like you have not yet given her the task, i.e. you are about to give her the task. She has not started yet but when she does, she will not be available until she finishes. I think the sentences would sound more natural if they included a word such as 'now' which clarifies any ambiguity. For example, `I have my assistant writing a report right now, so she is unavailable at the moment.`